# combine yymmdd and hour value in r

Tags: r, date, time

I have a raw data like this: (Both columns are numeric)

```
Date        Hour
20161107     0
20161107     1
20161107     2
20161108     8
20161108     13
```

I need to combine them and get:

```
Datetime
07/11/2016 00:00
07/11/2016 01:00
07/11/2016 02:00
08/11/2016 08:00
08/11/2016 13:00
```

I have tried to convert date from numeric to a date object:

```
as.Date(data[["Date"]], "%Y%m%d")
```

But it returns this:

```
Error in charToDate(x): character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

Does anybody have a solution for this?
Many thanks!

Comment: You can use `format( )` to get the format you want, but the object class will be converted to character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly advise using `lubridate` package, that will make your life easier. You just need the `ymd_h` function, giving in argument both your column in a single string (so using `paste0` for example).

```
library(lubridate)

df$Datetime <- ymd_h(paste0(df$Date," ",df$Hour))

     Date Hour            Datetime
1 20161107    0 2016-11-07 00:00:00
2 20161107    1 2016-11-07 01:00:00
3 20161107    2 2016-11-07 02:00:00
4 20161108    8 2016-11-08 08:00:00
5 20161108   13 2016-11-08 13:00:00
```

The data:

```
df <- read.table(text = "Date        Hour
                 20161107     0
                 20161107     1
                 20161107     2
                 20161108     8
                 20161108     13",header = T)
```

Comment: Many thanks. This looks fantastic. But is it possible to make it exactly in this format: "07/11/2016 08:00"? Because, after this, I need to compare this data with another data which is in the format of "07/11/2016 08:00". Thanks.

Comment: I would say you set your other data to the same format using the same ymd_h function, so you can make proper comparison

Comment: Thanks! You are right. I don't understand the reason behind it.I just tried several examples listed in ?ymd_h, and one of them just worked for my problem. Now I dare to meet my supervisor tomorrow. Thanks! Sincerely!

Answer (score 0):

I provide a base way, which uses `paste0()` to concatenate `Date` and `Hour` together and convert the object to the time class. In addition, you can change the format of the time class objects by `format()`. **Note:** The outcome of `format()` will be **character** class.

```
within(df, { time1 <- strptime(paste0(Date, Hour), "%Y%m%d%H")
             time2 <- format(time1, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M") } )

#       Date Hour              time2                 time1
# 1 20161107    0   07/11/2016 00:00   2016-11-07 00:00:00
# 2 20161107    1   07/11/2016 01:00   2016-11-07 01:00:00
# 3 20161107    2   07/11/2016 02:00   2016-11-07 02:00:00
# 4 20161108    8   08/11/2016 08:00   2016-11-08 08:00:00
# 5 20161108   13   08/11/2016 13:00   2016-11-08 13:00:00
```